# JRuby SSL binding creates broken thread if non SSL connection targets SSL Port

Tags: ssl, jruby, puma

Once I run an SSL server with puma:

```
bundle exec puma remote-webapp/config.ru -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:8888?keystore=remote-webapp/keystore.jks&keystore-pass=123456'
```

And then try to use http instead on the https, the following error occur:

```
vendor/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.9.2-java/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:56" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

The problem is then the particular thread would become a zombie and never got recycled. Is there anyway I could prevent this from happening?